# d3js append div return array of nulls

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to make a recurrent function where I send the children of the element clicked to be displayed. Everything seems fine till it is clicked and gets to the line of `cellSelection.enter().append("div");`

The nodes seem correct. I don't know what is happening exactly when it goes to the `append()` method.

Here is a working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/festudillobernal/LghxxqLv/

EDIT:

Here is the relevant code:

```
d3.json(dataJson, function(error, data) {
    display(dataJson);

    function display(data) {
        console.log(data);
        var nodes = treemap.nodes(data);
        var cellSelection = svg.selectAll(".cell").data(nodes);
        var cellEnterSelection = cellSelection.enter().append("div")
            .attr("class", "cell").on("click", zoomin);
        cellEnterSelection.append("div")
            .text(function(d) {
                return d.name ? d.name : "";
            });
        cellSelection.transition().duration(250)
            .call(cellUpdate);
        cellSelection.exit().remove();

        function zoomin(d) {
            if (transitioning || !d) return;
            transitioning = true;
            var g2 = display(d);
            var t1 = cellEnterSelection.transition().duration(750);
            var t2 = g2.transition().duration(750);
        }
        return cellEnterSelection;
    }
});
```

When clicking a cell and calling the `zoomin` function, it calls again the `display` method, at this step:

```
var cellEnterSelection = cellSelection.enter().append("div")
            .attr("class", "cell").on("click", zoomin);
```

Since it fills the `divs` with nulls, I already checked the return value of `cellSelection.enter().append("div")` and it is an array of nulls, any idea of what could be the cause?

Comment: While it is nice to have the fiddle link, please add the relevant code also in your question.

Comment: Added the relevant code ;)

Comment: Good, I made some minor adjustments for you.